# Diff doesn't recognise properly the link order changes

Tags: support, bug, review, suggested-edits, diff

This is [the diff result](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9305011) (as part of the review process for suggested edits):

[image]

and so on.

I believe the only change was a new link and as result the ordering changed (where the order is usually re-calculated automatically). I've approved that believing the links stayed the same, but still it's a messy way of showing that and it confuse the other reviewers what was actually the change about.

So in my opinion the only part which should be highlighted for changes should be the numbers, not the re-ordered content it-self, as the old links stayed the same.

---

Other example: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9511495).